# error in template variant of memcpy

Tags: c++, templates

I want to write template variant of memcpy:

```
template< typename T > 
inline T& MemCopy( T& dest, const T& src )
{
  *( T* )memcpy( &dest, &src, sizeof( src ) ) ;
}
```

When I try to compile in VS2010 the next code :

```
typedef short AMSync[ 4 ] ;
static AMPSync aSync ;

void Init( const AMPSync& sync )
{
   MemCopy( aSync, sync ) ;
}
```

I get error:

```
'T &MemCopy(T &,const T &)' : template parameter 'T' is ambiguous
          : see declaration of 'MemCopy'
          could be 'const short [4]'
          or       'AMPSync'
```

If I use:

```
template< typename T1, typename T2 > 
inline T1& MemCopy( T1& dest, const T2& src )
{
   *( T1* )memcpy( &dest, &src, sizeof( src ) ) ;
}
```

then errors are absent, but in this case compiler cannot check sizes of arguments

Is there way to achieve both purposes.

Comment: You can add a [tag:static-assert] to the second variant.

Comment: I spent a few minutes wondering about this, then realised you probably just have a typo. `AMPSync != AMSync`. [This](http://liveworkspace.org/code/1Z7Dq5$4) compiles.

Answer (score 0):

```
template<typename T1, typename T2> 
T1& MemCopy(T1& dest, const T2& src)
{
   static_assert(sizeof(src) == sizeof(dest));
   return *reinterpret_cast<T1*>(memcpy(&dest, &src, sizeof(src)));
}
```

or

```
template<typename T1, typename T2> 
typename std::enable_if<sizeof(T1) == sizeof(T2), T1&>::type MemCopy(T1& dest, const T2& src)
{
   return *reinterpret_cast<T1*>(memcpy(&dest, &src, sizeof(src)));
}
```

Though why do you want to do this? Your example would be better with:

```
static AMPSync aSync ;

void Init( const AMPSync& sync )
{
    aSync = sync;
}
```

Comment: Thank all of you for answers. But I see that I was not exact. I would want that types of parameters differ only by const modifier.  as regading variant with assigment. It will generate compiler error if asignment operator (=) is protected for some class. Of course, if it is done then simple copying is not recomeneded but in some cases it can be needed.